# Groups and Cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am studying the proof of the third Sylow's Theorem and I dont get this: Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, $N(H)= \{g \in G : gH=Hg \}$. Note that $G = \cup_{g \in G}AgA$ (where $A$ is any subgroup of $G$), and since $|HxH| = |Hx|$ for all $x \in N(H)$, $|G| = \sum_{x \notin N(H)}|HxH|+ \sum_{x\in N(H)}|Hx|$. They claim that $$\sum_{x\in N(H)}|Hx| = |N(H)|$$

And this is my question, why $\sum_{x\in N(H)}|Hx| = |N(H)|$? I know that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N(H)$, so this follow from Lagrange's Theorem? But, do we know that this sum is disjoint?

I was trying to find a proof of third Sylow Theorem that does not use group actions, do you know any?

Comment: I think they rather wanted to mean $\left|\bigcup_{x\in N(H)} Hx\right|$, or taking only one representative from each coset, otherwise the claim is false.

Comment: The sum cannot be over *all* elements: it adds up to too much. Just easily, take $G$ to be cyclic of order $2$, $p=2$. Then your left hand side is $2$, and your right hand side is the sum of $|Hx|=|G|$ *twice*, which adds up to $4$. You are taking a sum over double coset representatives, not all elements.

Comment: So, the sum needs to be over the quotiente group? $\sum_{Hx \in N(H)/H}|Hx| = |N(H)|$?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: You *could* do it over quotient group for that one, but then you are still messed up in the first summand. You should really do it over a family of coset representatives.

Comment: As for your last question, yes: Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* provides one.